# $esp register not found

Tags: gdb, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow

I am learning debugging with gdb and registers, but I am stuck in one point. As an instruction, I should print

```
print $esp


result: $1 = -9008
```

but I was expecting such result:

```
$2 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdcd0
```

In the next command, I need to enter that command:

```
x/24 $esp
```

Saying that no access to that register

```
Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffdce0
```

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be reading instructions from some `i386` tutorial, while using `x86_64` (64-bit) platform.

On `x86_64`, there is no `$esp` register, only the `$rsp` one.

Also note that calling convention on `x86_64` is different (arguments are not necessarily passed on stack), so your best course of action is to either find a new 64-bit tutorial, or to debug 32-bit target (usually you can build and run 32-bit programs on 64-bit hosts by compiling and linking them with `gcc -m32 ...`).

Comment: Thanks. I've changed to debug on i386 OS Linux and it works